# how to get change in sidebar in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sidebar

I have a sidebar in my project that there is some settings for my main page.
I want when my settings change in sidebar i emulate that change in my main page.
and of course i see this methode

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer ,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

 /** Called when drawer is closed */
 public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

 supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
 }

 /** Called when a drawer is opened */
 public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

 supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
 }
};
```

but my problem is when user touch any where in screen except sidebar ,sidebar going to closed and that method never called.
So how can i fix it?thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to use this code

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
        }
    });
```